# .Net Micro 4.2: Add existing project --> deploying failed

Tags: .net-micro-framework, netduino

I am trying to add an existing project ([this ServiceBus example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj190807.aspx)) to a .net micro 4.2 application. Visual Studio doesn't show any errors or relevant warnings, but if I try to deploy the app to my netduino I get an error message:

```
Incrementally deploying assemblies to device
Deploying assemblies for a total size of 71024 bytes
Assemblies not successfully deployed to device.
Deployment to the device was not successful.
```

and

```
An error has occurred.  Please check your hardware
```

Any idea how I can get more information about this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer in the [Netduino forum](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/5296-net-micro-42-add-existing-project-deploying-failed/page__view__findpost__p__34597).

The problem is, that my app is too big for the code memory (Deploying assemblies for a total size of 71024 bytes). Netduino plus only has 64KB code memory.